# Error while installing dlib for python3 on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pip, dlib

I'm trying to install face_recognition on windows environment but it was showing error while trying to install dlib. So, I tried to install dlib separately from command prompt using

```
pip install dlib
```

but it is again showing following error. I have already installed cmake and boost but nothing happens.

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.10.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    Complete output from command "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rln5gr2k\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-8m0ix2fi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rln5gr2k\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rln5gr2k\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rln5gr2k\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.6'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 15 2017
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/python.exe (found version "3.6.5")
    -- Found PythonLibs: C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/libs/Python36.lib
    -- pybind11 v2.2.2
    -- ******************************************************************************************
    -- Your version of Visual Studio has incomplete C++11 support and is unable to compile the
    -- DNN examples. So we are disabling the deep learning tools.  If you want to use the DNN
    -- tools in dlib then update your copy of Visual Studio.
    -- ******************************************************************************************
    -- Looking for sys/types.h
    -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
    -- Looking for stdint.h
    -- Looking for stdint.h - found
    -- Looking for stddef.h
    -- Looking for stddef.h - found
    -- Check size of void*
    -- Check size of void* - done
    -- Enabling SSE4 instructions
    -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
    -- Searching for BLAS and LAPACK
    -- Looking for pthread.h
    -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
    -- Found Threads: TRUE
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
    -- Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "7.5")
    -- *** Dlib CUDA support requires C++11 but your compiler doesn't support it. ***
    -- Disabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL NOT USE CUDA
    -- C++11 activated.
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (message):
      You have to use a version of Visual Studio that supports C++11.  As of
      December 2017, the only versions that have good enough C++11 support to
      compile the dlib Pyhton API is a fully updated Visual Studio 2015 or a
      fully updated Visual Studio 2017.  Older versions of either of these
      compilers have bad C++11 support and will fail to compile the Python
      extension.  ***SO UPDATE YOUR VISUAL STUDIO TO MAKE THIS ERROR GO AWAY***


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-rln5gr2k/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-rln5gr2k/dlib/build/temp.win32-3.6/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rln5gr2k\dlib\setup.py", line 249, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rln5gr2k\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rln5gr2k\dlib\setup.py", line 163, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rln5gr2k\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rln5gr2k\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rln5gr2k\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.6']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rln5gr2k\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-8m0ix2fi-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rln5gr2k\dlib\
```

Comment: The error says you're using old Visual Studio. Are you? What error was it showing earlier?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017. It was showing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution simply by updating the Visual Studio. The earlier build doesn't have the complete C++11 support so by updating it, the dlib gets compiled without any error.

Comment: I am already using latest version of VS which is Visual Studio 19 but still facing this error. Any guess??

Comment: Solved it! Even after having VS19 my C++ extensions were missing so downloading them solved the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is open command prompt and type pip install dlib. If this doesn't work for you.. reinstall python and click on the 'environment variables'. This might solve the problem.If it continues please don't hesitate to ask.